# How to save a record with validation rule in place

Tags: validation, salesforce

I currently have a validation rule that prevents user from making changes to a record when its status is completed. Users are only allowed to make changes if the status is either draft or registered.

```
AND(
TEXT(Current_Status__c) <> "Draft",
TEXT(Current_Status__c) <> "Registered"
)
```

There is a new requirement to allow user to update only a specific picklist value field even if the record status is completed. If i remove the validation rule, user will be able to change any fields on the page layout which won't work.

Object setting for the profile is read, create, edit. This object is a child object to Opportunity, OWD is controlled by parent.

Any recommendation on how to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We can rewrite your rule as `ISPICKVAL(Current_Status__c, 'Completed')` for example, looks bit cleaner. Your call though, you can keep as is.

So what you'd need is something like `ISPICKVAL(Current_Status__c, 'Completed') && !ISCHANGED(Some_Picklist__c)`. It should let the edit through if you're modifying that picklist.

The problem is it won't check if that's the only change. Usercan cheat, modify 10 fields and they'll "piggyback" and save OK as long as one of them is that picklist.

It's pain to write validation like `ISPICKVAL(Current_Status__c, 'Completed') && !ISCHANGED(Some_Picklist__c) && (ISCHANGED(Field1__c) || ISCHANGED(Field2__c) || ISCHANGED(Field3__c))`. You'd have to add all editable fields to it, change it every time you make new one. And eventually you'll hit length limits.

I know 3 options for this if it's a concern for you:

- Ask a developer to rewrite your logic to Apex trigger, it could then go dynamic through all fields (using "describe" calls to learn field names or stuff like [`getPopulatedFieldsAsMap`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).
- Another trick is to allow editing completed records only through a quick action, not normal edit page. In that action you could set some hidden checkbox in the field prepopulating step and your validation would let the save through only if that checkbox is set. But then you need to deactivate it somehow anyway or the bypass will get permamently enabled.
- If you don't have too many record types on the object a common trick is to change the record type on completion (workflow, process builder etc). And have another page layout with all fields locked down except that special picklist. It works good enough for UI changes but won't protect if you have code and integrations writing to the object too.